# How to hide sdl screen in sdl version 1.2.5?

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, screen, avi

I have made a movie player using ffmpeg and sdl 1.2.5 in MFC to play avi.

When I send video-image to my mfc-viewer insted of sending them to sdl screen, every play is OK, but when I play avi, sdl screen is popup which is not how it should do it.

Is it possible to hide sdl screen in version 1.2 or is there any way to hide sdl screen like hiding sdl-screen of MFC-viewer and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDL_HideWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HideWindow) to hide your window if that is what you mean by "screen".

Comment: is there sdl_hideWindow on sdl 1.2.5 ? i dont want to change current sdl version